# Maintaining a multi-submodule project using git

Tags: git, github, fuelphp

I'm developing a website with two other team members using the FuelPHP framework. I would like to use git to maintain the project, but I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around the configuration. When I use `oil` to install FuelPHP, it installs the main framework as well as several submodules from github. The `.git/config` file in the document root looks like this:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = git://github.com/fuel/fuel.git
[branch "1.4/master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/1.4/master
[submodule "docs"]
        url = git://github.com/fuel/docs.git
[submodule "fuel/core"]
        url = git://github.com/fuel/core.git
[submodule "fuel/packages/auth"]
        url = git://github.com/fuel/auth.git
[submodule "fuel/packages/email"]
        url = git://github.com/fuel/email.git
[submodule "fuel/packages/oil"]
        url = git://github.com/fuel/oil.git
[submodule "fuel/packages/orm"]
        url = git://github.com/fuel/orm.git
[submodule "fuel/packages/parser"]
        url = git://github.com/fuel/parser.git
```

I have a bare repository setup on a remote server where I would like to maintain this project. I'd like to have the ability to pull updates from github for FuelPHP and it's submodules, while also being able to push any changes to the bare repository so my team members and production server can pull from it. So far I'm running into a brick wall.

Here's what I've done so far:

On the server:

```
$ mkdir websitename.git
$ cd websitename.git
$ git init --bare
```

On my local machine:

```
$ curl get.fuelphp.com/oil | sh
$ oil create websitename
$ cd websitename/
$ git remote add reponame ssh://git@example.com:2222/httpd/www/websitename.git
$ git push reponame 1.4/master
```

I get this response:

```
Counting objects: 14422, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4375/4375), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14422/14422), 2.20 MiB | 3.82 MiB/s, done.
Total 14422 (delta 9816), reused 14410 (delta 9810)
To ssh://haroldbr@haroldinc.com:2222/home/haroldbr/public_html/crude.git
 * [new branch]      1.4/master -> 1.4/master
```

Then, on the server again:

```
$ git clone -l --no-hardlinks /httpd/www/websitename.git /httpd/www/websitename
```

which gives me this error:

```
Cloning into 'websitename'...
done.
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
```

Clearly I have a configuration problem, but I have no idea what it is. I want to be able to update all of the files in my remote repository using `git`. I envision it working something like:

On my local machine:

```
$ git pull origin 1.4/master
$ git push reponame --all
```

On the server:

```
$ cd websitename/
$ git pull
```

In a perfect world, this would pull all updates for FuelPHP and it's packages from github and push all of those updates, along with any changes to the files in `app/` or `public/` to the bare repository. Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Do I need to setup repositories in `app/` and `public/` and maintain them separately? And what is wrong with my configuration that I can't clone from the bare repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a screencast on how to use git to maintain a FuelPHP website project here: http://blip.tv/fuelphp/creating-a-fuelphp-application-repository-5688973, but it doesn't cover pushing to a bare repository.

Assuming that you already have a new bare repository setup at ssh://example.com/path/to/project.git, you can follow these steps to setup your project. From your local machine:

```
git clone -b 1.4/master --recursive git://github.com/fuel/fuel.git /path/to/project
cd /path/to/project
rm -R .git
rm .gitmodules
rm -R docs
git init
git submodule add git://github.com/fuel/core.git fuel/core
git submodule add git://github.com/fuel/auth.git fuel/packages/auth
git submodule add git://github.com/fuel/email.git fuel/packages/email
git submodule add git://github.com/fuel/oil.git fuel/packages/oil
git submodule add git://github.com/fuel/orm.git fuel/packages/orm
git submodule add git://github.com/fuel/parser.git fuel/packages/parser
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin master ssh://example.com/path/to/project.git
git push origin master
```

You can then go to your production server and clone from the remote repository recursively to get your entire project:

```
git clone --recursive ssh://example.com/path/to/project.git /path/to/production
```

You'll then be able to track changes to your project while maintaining the ability to:

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

which will keep you up to date with the latest FuelPHP packages.

Answer (score 0):

You are cloning successfully but you just need to checkout what branch you want after. Since you don't have head defined on the bare repo, it gives you that warning.

Also, `git clone --recursive` should be done once which will get your submodules as well. From then, you can do a `git pull` followed by a `git submodule update`

Comment: I tried `git clone --recursive --no-hardlinks -l websitename.git websitename` and it gave me this error: `Cloning into 'websitename'... done. Submodule 'fuel/core' (git://github.com/fuel/core.git) registered for path 'fuel/core' Cloning into 'fuel/core'... fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=Connection refused Clone of 'git://github.com/fuel/core.git' into submodule path 'fuel/core' failed`

Comment: You don't have a key on that machine to connect to github. So, clone without recursive, then `git submodule init`, then use `sed` to change the urls to the read-only form, then `git submodule update`. If you are not going to be contributing to fuel, you might as well just use the read-only form of the url and the server will be able to pull it down. The HTTP form will do it.

Comment: I used `git clone --no-hardlinks -l websitename.git websitename`. Then `cd websitename` and `find . -exec grep "git://" '{}' \; -exec sed -i 's/git:\/\//http:\/\//' '{}' \;` to replace `git://` with `http://`. I ran `git submodule init` and `git submodule update`, which successfully let me clone the fuel core from github. However, my server repo still doesn't look like my local repo. I can create a file, stage it, commit it, then push to the bare repo. However, when I try to pull to the live server, it's telling me `Already up-to-date.` Do I need to change the branch name or something?

Comment: Yes, after you clone, make sure to set up tracking so that pull will do something. `git branch --set-upstream origin/master`. Now pull should work.